# How to play video in the iPhone without using MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone

Is this possible to play any video file without using of `MPMoviePlayerController` in iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can also use a UIWebView.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976652/pros-and-cons-of-mpmovieplayercontroller-versus-launching-uiwebview-to-stream-mov/1573886#1573886).

Comment: Is this possible to play video file in resource folder of our project using UIWebView.... ?

Comment: Sorry . I got an answer for playing video file in resource folder using UIWebView

Comment: Why some of the video file doesnot play for both UIWebView and MPMoviePlayerController ?

Is this any encoder and decoder problem.I want to play any type of video file in iphone ? Is this possible ?

Comment: Not all video formats are supported.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535836/video-file-formats-supported-in-iphone/1535876#1535876

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web view but you can play only those videos present in the bundle, you cannot play any format in iPhone as some of the formats are not supported.

[See this link](http://www.ifuniavideoconverter.com/knowledge/iphone-support-video-formats.html)