# iPhone UIWebView/Safari.app iOS 4 video/movie - Server issue?

Tags: iphone, video, safari, ios4

I have a UIWebView which loads videos from an external server. The code seems to be fine since it works when I try to host my videos on another server.
Are there any changes since iOS 3.0 which the server didn't need to have? (Where it loaded without problems).

The easiest way to test it is to load the url in the inbuilt Safari.app, on most servers I get "This movie could not be played", on my local webserver and an external virtual Server it works.

So I suppose there need to be some specific new server settings for iOS video playback?

Desperately looking for help

Comment: Does iOS 3 work properly? You are not being clear about that...

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to play .flv files ?

Comment: Yes it did work on iOS 3. I'm trying to play mp4 files, I tried several encoding programs like Handbrake, XMedia Recode and iTunes export

Comment: Edit: I'm trying Quicktime X to reencode my video "for web" with the reference to 3gp and m4v files. And it might work, I don't know why it doesn't load mp4s anymore

Comment: false positive... it doesn't work apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User @cduhn suggested looking in to MIME return types of the server, and that seemed to be the answer. I contacted my host to add all apple specific MIME types (3gp, m4v and mp4) and now it's working. Strange it worked in 3.0 without them.

Answer (score 0):

Look into file permissions. I've had issues developing local webpages that didn't have proper permissions for the browser to load them.

My guess is that the servers that work are Windows based, whereas the the ones that don't are Linux based. Linux is generally more strict about permissions.

Comment: Servers I tried are all on Linux. I tried file permissions and file owner changes, but no luck. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Permissions have to be set on all levels all the way up to the root in some cases, not just the current file or the directory. Try completely unlocking everything permisisonswise and then if it works, slowly secure other folders until you encounter the problem "branch" of your directory tree.